# What is differentiability and how do we prove it

Tags: limits, functions, derivatives, continuity

I can't understand the concept but all I know is that a function must be continuous to be differentiable
for example $$ f(x)=\begin{cases} 2x^2 +3x-1 \;if x\le 0 \\
                     \frac{x^2-4}{2}-2x+1 \;if x\gt 0 \end{cases}$$
first step is to prove it's continuous so:
$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+} f(x)= \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{x^2-4}{2}-2x+1 = \lim_{x\to 0^+}=-1 $$
$$\lim_{x\to 0^-} f(x)= \lim_{x\to 0^-}  2x^2 +3x-1 = \lim_{x\to 0^-}=-1=f(0) $$
Then it is continuous but what happens next? How can we find differentiability using the definition?

Comment: Is there a specific example that you could post that you don't understand to make the question more specific

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are not likely to get a good answer because your question is much too general. You are really asking about the whole first few weeks of calculus. Please edit the question to make it more specific. Explain what you do know and where you are stuck.

Comment: I did @EthanBolker

Comment: The derivative is the limit of the difference quotient $(f(x+h)-f(x))/h$ as $h$ approaches $0$. There's no problem with your example except possibly at $x=0$.You  can use the same technique there as you did for continuity to test whether derivative at $0$ exists: see what happens from the right and from the left. You might want to draw a picture first so you know what to expect.

Answer (score 2):

Differentiability is a property of functions. If $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, then we say that $f$ is differentiable if $$\lim_{h\to 0}\left(\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right)$$ exists and we call the value of this limit the derivative of $f$ at $x$. This is often denoted as $f'(x)$.

If you look at the limit itself, you can see that for $h$ fixed, it represents the gradient of the line connecting two points on the graph of $f$ that are separated by a distance $h$. As we take $h$ to $0$, this chord becomes a tangent to the curve at that point.

[image]

This tangent has the same gradient as the curve at the intersection point, so the limit is useful because we can use it to find the gradient of a curve at a particular point.

You make a good point in saying that a function must be continuous to be differentiable, but you should try to think of some examples of continuous curves that are not differentiable.

Comment: I saw something about finding lim x→0 (f(x)-f(a))/x-a does that work

Comment: That is wrong. It is right if you take the limit as $x \rightarrow a$. `You can prove that this is equivalent to the formula above by simply letting $h = a-x$

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, a function is differentiable iff, when you zoom in on a small piece of it, it looks straight.

For instance, if you zoom in on the graph of $y = x^2$ at any point on the graph, say $x = x_0$, then the graph will look like a line, and that line has slope $2x_0$.

On the other hand, if you zoom in on the graph of $|x|$ at the origin, it will be shaped like a "V" no matter how much you zoom in. Thus that function is not differentiable at that point.